# Alternative Database Tools for Web Admin

Tags: mysql, tools

I currently use phpmyadmin for most of my database administration.  It works well enough, but I'm interested in other tools that might work more quickly/efficiently/etc...

What are the best and/or alternative admin tools for MySQL on a *nix box?

Comment: Are you looking for web replacements? Or native clients using the OS GUI?

Comment: i'm looking for web replacements, almost all of my systems that I have db's running are linux servers, so no GUI

Comment: @Patrick , yes GUI if you can connect from outside the server network . you can then use SQLyog , SequelPro ... or whatever desktop application you like best , such a desktop app would be faster and better than a web replacement .

Comment: I think this should be retitled to indicate that it's for MySQL in particular, and not generically for all databases. ... idk, maybe just over pedanticness.

Comment: @Brian ~ per the meta question I don't think we need to do this. http://meta.dba.stackexchange.com/questions/92/should-all-questions-be-actual-questions

Comment: Comment removed, due to meta discussion. I'd still like the title more... titly though.

Comment: There is also DbFacePHP for MySQL http://www.dbfacephp.com, though it's not free now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A list of web replacements is available here:

- http://www.webdesigneronline.co.uk/10-great-alternatives-to-phpmyadmin

And this question was asked before in Stackoverflow as well:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324972/ajax-phpmyadmin-alternative

In my opinion, a *alternative* phpmyadmin should not just look good, but must at all cost keep up with security updates. If you are intranet user, it might be a different case, but I know from the early days of phpmyadmin that security is very important for anything involving "http and sql" ;-)

Comment: Do we need to migrate these sorts of questions from SO then?

Answer (score 4):

I myself use [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/):

> SQLyog MySQL GUI is the most powerful
>   MySQL manager and admin tool,
>   combining the features of MySQL
>   Administrator, phpMyAdmin and other
>   MySQL Front Ends and MySQL GUI tools.

And sometimes use [MySQL WorkBench](http://wb.mysql.com/):

> is a visual database design tool that
>   integrates SQL development,
>   administration, database design,
>   creation and maintenance into a
>   single, seamless environment for the
>   MySQL database system. It is the
>   successor to DBDesigner 4 from
>   fabFORCE.net, and replaces the
>   previous package of software, MySQL
>   GUI Tools Bundle.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use [Webmin](http://www.webmin.com/)(for MySQL on a Linux box).  It lets you handle your databases mostly without needing any actual SQL.  Also, it can do a host of other things including remotely installing modules, servers, if you have a mail server you can check the mail through Webmin too.  You can change passwords, view logs, view cron jobs, and it has a shell too.

Comment: I thought webmin just rolled in phpMyAdmin and phpMyPostgresql? (or whatever, point remains)

Comment: @jcolebrand: What do you mean by "just rolled in"?

Comment: "just folded in"? That the webmin toolkit didn't write their own universal database access methods, they merely used somebody else's toolkit as part of their own.

Comment: @jcolebrand: I don't know if that is the case.  When I read up on PhpMyadmin and Webmin, Webmin looked better to me so that's the one I picked.  I find it incredibly useful and haven't used anything else since. or ever, for that matter(If you have something good, why change it?).

Comment: I'll do a bit of digging and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

There's also [SQLBuddy](http://www.sqlbuddy.com/), though unfortunately it seems it's [no longer under development](http://groups.google.com/group/sql-buddy/browse_thread/thread/9ce741a34962994d#).

Answer (score 1):

take a look DbFacePHP for MySQL, live demo there
http://www.dbfacephp.com/mockup/index.php
the best

BTW: I found it on Alternativeto

http://alternativeto.net/software/dbfacephp-for-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You can use Chive

http://www.chive-project.com/

**What is Chive?**

> Chive is a next generation MySQL database management tool. The
>   web-based user interface supports most of the common operations needed
>   by software developers and database admins (databases, tables,
>   indices, keys, triggers, views, routines, privileges management,
>   import/export).